# Merge on x1, or if no match x2, or if no match x3

Tags: r, merge

I'm trying to merge 2 datasets on a key, but if there is no match then I want to try another key, and so on.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(5,1,7,3),
              b=c("T","T","T","F"),
              c=c("F","T","F","F"))


df2 <- data.frame(x1=c(4,5,3,9), 
                  x2=c(7,8,1,2),
                  x3=c("g","w","t","o"))
df1
   a  b  c
1  5  T  F
2  1  T  T
3  7  T  F
4  3  F  F

df2
   x1 x2 x3 ..
1  4  7  g  ..
2  5  8  w  ..
3  3  1  t  ..
4  9  2  o  ..
```

The desired output is something like

```
   a  b  c x3  ..
1  5  T  F  w  ..
2  1  T  T  t  ..
3  7  T  F  g  ..
4  3  F  F  t  ..
```

I tried something along the lines of

```
dfm <- merge(df1,df2, by.x = "a", by.y = "x1", all.x = TRUE)
dfm <- merge(dfm,df2, by.x = "a", by.y = "x2", all.x = TRUE)
```

but that isn't quite right.

Comment: Please check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, there is a discrepancy between the title of your question and the sample data and expected result. The question is titled _Merge on x1, or if no match x2, or if no match x3_ but column `x3` in the given sample dataset is not used for matching (and cannot be used as it has the wrong type).

Comment: Ah, you are right.  The sample data I provided does not use x3 as an addition key to try and match.  Fortunately, the answers provided scale perfectly to x3, x4, ect.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really isn't a standard sort of merge. You can make it more standard by reshaping `df2` so you have just one field to merge on

```
df2long <- rbind(
    data.frame(a = df2$x1, df2[,-(1:2), drop=FALSE]), 
    data.frame(a = df2$x2, df2[,-(1:2), drop=FALSE])
)
dfm <- merge(df1, df2long, by = "a", all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: Very concise solution to the problem.  Thanks so much for your quick response!

Comment: This answer returns the expected result only for the given sample datasets. But it will return duplicate entries if there is a match in both columns `x1` and `x2`. Please, see the enhanced datasets [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52636778/3817004).

Comment: That's a good catch, @Uwe.   A quick fix for removing duplicates is a simple `df[!duplicated(df),]`.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
matches <- lapply(df2[, c("x1", "x2")], function(x) match(df1$a, x))
# finding matches in df2$x1 and df2$x2
# notice that the code below should work with any number of columns to be matched:
# you just need to add the names here eg. df2[, paste0("x", 1:100)] 
matches
```

> ```
> $x1
> [1]  2 NA NA  3
>
> $x2
> [1] NA  3  1 NA
> ```

```
combo <- Reduce(function(a,b) "[<-"(a, is.na(a), b[is.na(a)]), matches)
# combining the matches on "first come first served" basis
combo
```

> ```
> [1] 2 3 1 3
> ```

```
cbind(df1, df2[combo,])
```

> ```
>     a b c x1 x2 x3
> 2   5 T F  5  8  w
> 3   1 T T  3  1  t
> 1   7 T F  4  7  g
> 3.1 3 F F  3  1  t
> ```

Comment: Since OP's desired output doesn't have x1, x2, could do `cbind(df1, df2[combo, -which(names(df2) %in% c("x1", "x2")), drop=FALSE])` if that matters.

Comment: Clever approach to the problem, definitely helpful in seeing your thought process to arrive at the solution.  Many thanks!

Comment: This approach returns the expected result also with the more complete use cases [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52636778/3817004). Furthermore, precedence can be controlled.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the OP has requested to try a match of `a` with `x1` first, then - if failed - to try to match `a` with `x2`. So any match of `a` with `x1` should take precedence over a match of `a` with `x2`.

Unfortunately, the sample data set provided by the OP does *not* include a use case to prove this. Therefore, I have modified the sample dataset accordingly (see *Data* section).

The approach suggested here is to reshape `df2` from wide to long format (likewise to [MrFlick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52635001/3817004)) but to use a `data.table` join with parameter `mult = "first"`.

The columns of `df2` to be considered as key columns *and the precedence* can be controlled by the `measure.vars` parameter to `melt()`. After reshaping, `melt()` arranges the rows in the column order given in `measure.vars`:

```
library(data.table)
# define cols of df2 to use as key in order of 
key_cols <- c("x1", "x2")
# reshape df2 from wide to long format
long <- melt(setDT(df2), measure.vars = key_cols, value.name = "a")
# join long with df1, pick first matches
result <- long[setDT(df1), on = "a", mult = "first"]
# clean up
setcolorder(result, names(df1))
result[, variable := NULL]
result
```

> ```
>    a b c   x3
> 1: 5 T F    w
> 2: 1 T T    t
> 3: 7 T F    g
> 4: 3 F F    t
> 5: 0 F F <NA>
> ```

Please, note that the original row order of `df1` has been preserved.

Also, note that the code works for an arbitrary number of key columns. The precedence of key columns can be easily changed. E.g., if the order is reversed, i.e., `key_cols <- c("x2", "x1")` matches of `a` with `x2` will be picked first.

#### Data

Enhanced sample datasets:

`df1` has an additional row with no match in `df2`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(5,1,7,3,0),
                  b=c("T","T","T","F","F"),
                  c=c("F","T","F","F","F"))
df1
```

> ```
>    a b c
> 1: 5 T F
> 2: 1 T T
> 3: 7 T F
> 4: 3 F F
> 5: 0 F F
> ```

`df2` has an additional row to prove that a match in `x1` takes precedence over a match in `x2`. The value `5` appears twice: In row 2 of column `x1` and in row 5 of column `x2`.

```
df2 <- data.frame(x1=c(4,5,3,9,6), 
                  x2=c(7,8,1,2,5),
                  x3=c("g","w","t","o","n"))
df2
```

> ```
>    x1 x2 x3
> 1:  4  7  g
> 2:  5  8  w
> 3:  3  1  t
> 4:  9  2  o
> 5:  6  5  n
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your question, but rather than repetitive merging I'd compare the keys of the potential merge, if this number is >0, than you have a match. If you want to take the first column with a match you can try this:

```
    library(tidyr)
    library(purrr)
    (df1 <- data.frame(a=c(5,1,7,3),
          b=c("T","T","T","F"),
          c=c("F","T","F","F")) )
    (df2 <- data.frame(x1=c(4,5,3,9), 
              x2=c(7,8,1,2),
              x3=c("g","w","t","o")) )

     FirstColMatch<-1:ncol(df2) %>% 
         map(~intersect(df1$a, df2[[.x]])) %>% 
         map(length)  %>%
         detect_index(function(x)x>0)

     NewDF<-merge(df1,df2,by.x="a", by.y =names(df2)[FirstColMatch])
```